# How to convert the API response format into Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I have this code using which I am able to download data from API. But I don't know how to convert this to pandas data frame.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://statdb.luke.fi:443/PxWeb/api/v1/en/LUKE/02 Maatalous/04 Tuotanto/06 Lihantuotanto/02 Kuukausitilastot/02_Lihantuotanto_teurastamoissa_kk.px"

payload = json.dumps({
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Muuttuja",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Lihantuotanto"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Laji",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Lehmät"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "csv"
  }
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'rxid=710a361a-7044-494f-95b7-15261822712c'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The code returns a text format data. I need guidance on how to make a pandas data frame with this output.

For this particular data frame, the Column headers would be

"Month",

"Variable",

"Cows 7) 8)"

So on and So forth.

Comment: What would be the expected DataFrame format?

Comment: Like this table: https://statdb.luke.fi/PxWeb/pxweb/en/LUKE/LUKE__02%20Maatalous__04%20Tuotanto__06%20Lihantuotanto__02%20Kuukausitilastot/02_Lihantuotanto_teurastamoissa_kk.px/table/tableViewLayout2/

Comment: The data frame would have the following columns: "Month", "Variable", "Cows 7) 8)" as per this json query shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StringIO` to mimic a file-like object and then create a `pd.DataFrame` from it. Additionally, there are some weird symbols in the first column (`ï»¿`), which I expect you don't need. Therefore, make sure to rename the first column as well.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

url = "https://statdb.luke.fi:443/PxWeb/api/v1/en/LUKE/02 Maatalous/04 Tuotanto/06 Lihantuotanto/02 Kuukausitilastot/02_Lihantuotanto_teurastamoissa_kk.px"

payload = json.dumps({   "query": [
    {
      "code": "Muuttuja",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Lihantuotanto"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Laji",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Lehmät"
        ]
      }
    }   ],   "response": {
    "format": "csv"   } })

headers = {   'Content-Type': 'application/json',   'Cookie': 'rxid=710a361a-7044-494f-95b7-15261822712c' }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

# Create StringIO object to mimic file-like object
content_file = StringIO(response.text)

# Create pd.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(content_file)

# Clean column name
df.rename(columns = {'ï»¿"Month"': 'Month'}, inplace = True)

print(df.head())
```